# Powershell - Check number for several ranges

Tags: powershell

Hi I am new to Powershell and need some help:
My Script gets a number by userinput. I want to check this number if it´s between these ranges. So far so easy, but the input from 1-9 is with a leading zero.
With google, I got this working without the special case "leading zero".

```
do {
    try {
        $numOk = $true
        $input = Read-host "Write a number between 1-12"
        } # end try
    catch {$numOK = $false }
} # end do 
# check numbers
until (
    ($input -ge 1 -and $input -lt 13) -or
    ($input -ge 21 -and $input -lt 25) -or
    ($input -ge 41 -and $input -lt 49) -or
    ($input -ge 61 -and $input -lt 67) -and $numOK)

Write-Host $input
```

For example:

- Input "5" Output "5"
- Input "05" stucks in loop, should be "05"

AddOn: Is it possible to block inputs like 1-9 and just accept inputs like 01-09?

Comment: Try reading about string formats and parsing strings, on this link, `http://goo.gl/0JfuDc` and ask an actual  question if you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the -f operator to format the string here is to get a 2 digits number

```
PS>"{0:00}" -f 5  
05
```

some readings : http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html